# Initiating WP_Query() with no args and adding them later through the query() method

Tags: wp-query

I've inherited maintenance of a theme from another developer, and I'm trying to understand if there's a good reason why they did this.

The theme includes a page template that runs a custom query for posts. It's set up like this:

```php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query();
    $query->query('posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged=' . $paged);
```

What I do, and what I've always seen others do, is pass in the query arguments while creating the new class instance, i.e. `new WP_Query($args);`

Does calling the `$query->query($args)` method do anything different? Is it identical from a performance perspective? (I want to make sure it's not hitting the database twice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does calling the `$query->query($args)` method do anything different?

`$query = new WP_Query( $args );` is simply a shortcut to the "*instantiate class first, query later*" version like `$query = new WP_Query; $posts = $query->query( $args );`. You can see it from the class constructor source [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/__construct/#source):

```php
public function __construct( $query = '' ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query ) ) {
        $this->query( $query );
    }
}
```

> Is it identical from a performance perspective? (I want to make sure
>   it's not hitting the database twice.)

Yes, unless of course you do something like this:

```php
$args = [ 'paged' => 2 ];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $query->query( $args );
```

Then that means double queries.

However, there's a difference in the return value:

```php
$query = new WP_Query( $args );  // returns an object
$posts = $query->query( $args ); // returns an array
```

And `get_posts()` ([source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#source)) for example, uses the second approach.

> I'm trying to understand if there's a good reason why they did this

I don't know why did they do it that way, but it is **perfectly fine** (although the code would be a few bytes more compact when using direct query upon instantiating the class). And I'd concern more on using the proper query parameters; e.g. using the proper post type, and setting `no_found_rows` to `true` when you don't need pagination — in fact, setting it to `true` can improve performance.